# How to include jquery ui slider in wordpress theme correctly?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am trying to include jquery ui slider into wordpress divi theme project. But slider is not working. I am not sure, maybe I am not including css or something. But I would like to include jquery ui directly form Wordpress, not from external file. So, how to include and use further the jquery ui slider in wordpress divi theme?

```
<div id="slider1" class="uiSlider">
    <div id="custom-handle1" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
<script>
var handle1 = jQuery( "#custom-handle1" );

  jQuery(function($){
    jQuery("#slider1" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      min: 10,
      max: 100,
      step: 5,
        create: function() {
          handle1.text( jQuery( this ).slider( "value" ) );
            console.log('a');
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('c');
          handle1.html( ui.value );
      },
      change: function( event, ui) {
                console.log('b');
      }
  });
  }); 
</script>



function add_jquery_ui(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jquery_ui' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Acually these are the basic files for jQuery UI Slider

css - https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
js - https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"

For reference : https://www.javatpoint.com/jquery-ui-slider

Then download and create save js files into js folder and css file in to css folder of child theme ( wp-content/themes/child-theme-name/js and wp-content/themes/child-theme-name/css )

In the functions.php ( Your child theme )

```
function add_jquery_ui(){

// add jquery file if you required like following

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-ui.js', array(), '', true );

// add css files

wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/jquery-ui.css', array(), '', 'all' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jquery_ui' );
```

You can download and use your compatible jQuery UI package.

Comment: jQuery file still is not being added. Where the problem could be?

Comment: Please download the jquery from here http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js. And add in the function  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-1.10.2.js', array(), '', true );

Comment: it is still not working. no jquery ui and no jquery are being included in the source code..

Comment: where did you put that code? in child theme's functions.php and the js and css files are in child theme's folder right?

Comment: yes. I am wondering maybe there is a plugin for number sider to use in calculations? because this does not work..

Comment: the above slider is not a numbered slider. if you need need to add your js function.https://www.javatpoint.com/oprweb/test.jsp?filename=jqueryuislider3

Comment: I dont need a range slider, I need a simple slider to use its values later in calculations. But with my theme the scripts do not appear. So I am thinking about wordpress plugin. Maybe you know any?